# loop is stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: java

Why is this code not ending. I have given the required string input and k input, but I don't know why it is not ending. Please provide some insights.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        int k = sc.nextInt();
        ArrayList<Character> l = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
            l.add(s.charAt(i));
        }
        
        int count = 0;
        
        int first = 0;
        int last = s.length() - 1;
        
        while(first < last){
            if(l.get(first) + l.get(first + 1) == k || l.get(first) == k){
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(count % 2 == 0){
            System.out.println("B");
        }
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you never change `first` or `last`.

Comment: Under which conditions would it stop looping?

Comment: Your `while(first < last)` is not ending, `first` and `last` remain same through out iteration

Answer (score 1):

Your input is fine for now. The issue is `first` and `last` stays same throughout the iteration. Add `first++;` in your while loop, so that at each iteration `first` value increments.

```
while(first < last){
    if(l.get(first) + l.get(first + 1) == k || l.get(first) == k){
        count++;
    }
    first++;
}
```